# accessing the selected class over which mouse is pointed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to access the specific class and apply the below codes when the mouse is hovered over a specific class. I'm using the same class name for 4 different divs. how should i do it?

```
<div class="block"><span class="gradient"> <span class="block-show">Tech Blogs</span> </span></div>
<div class="block"><span class="gradient"> <span class="block-show">Tech Blogs</span> </span></div>
<div class="block"><span class="gradient"> <span class="block-show">Tech Blogs</span> </span></div>
<div class="block"><span class="gradient"> <span class="block-show">Tech Blogs</span> </span></div>
```

```js
$('.block').each(function(obj){
    obj.mouseenter(function(){
        $('.gradient').animate({
            height: "8em"
        });
        $('.block-show').animate({fontSize: '1em'});
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $('.gradient').animate({
            height: "2em"
        });
        $('.block-show').animate({fontSize: '0.5em'});
    });
});
```

Comment: What is/are your questions? Thanks

Comment: Show the relevent html also and exactly what it's that you want out of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$(this)` to refer to the element you have clicked.

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="xyz" name="button">A</button>
<button type="button" class="xyz" name="button">B</button>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('.xyz').hover(function() {
    // here you can do what you want to do when the mouse enters
    $(this).css("background-color","yellow");
}, function() {
    // here you can do what you want to do when the mouse leaves
    $(this).css("background-color","red");
});
```

Comment: i want to use hover effect not the click

Comment: Simply replace '.click' with '.hover'

Comment: actually i have a div of dimension 400*400px and class "block" and then over it "gradient" class dimension 100*400. when i hover over the div element then gradient class dimension becomes 400*400. so i want to apply this effect only with that div element over which the mouse is hovered. in my case it happens with all the divs

Comment: give me your email id

Answer (score 0):

Use `on` method and `mouseover` event, like this:

```
$('element').on("mouseover", function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('class'))
})
```

Comment: bro can i get your email id i need to show a picture through which only i can tell you my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event in the function

```
obj.mouseenter(function(event){
$(event.currentTarget).animate({
    height: "8em"
});
```